# Jenkins rally plugin not working

Tags: jenkins, rally

I am using rally plugin with jenkins and  on running the build i am getting below error

```
rally update plug-in error: could not update changeset entry: null
com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyAssetNotFoundException
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.utils.RallyQueryBuilder.andExecuteReturningRef(RallyQueryBuilder.java:65)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.createRepository(RallyConnector.java:187)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.service.RallyService.updateChangeset(RallyService.java:46)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyPlugin.perform(RallyPlugin.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
    rally update plug-in error: could not update TaskDetails entry: null
com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyAssetNotFoundException
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.utils.RallyQueryBuilder.andExecuteReturningObject(RallyQueryBuilder.java:84)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.queryForTaskById(RallyConnector.java:107)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.service.RallyService.getTaskObjectByStoryRef(RallyService.java:140)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.service.RallyService.updateRallyTaskDetails(RallyService.java:108)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyPlugin.perform(RallyPlugin.java:117)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
    rally update plug-in error: could not update changeset entry: null
com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyAssetNotFoundException
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.utils.RallyQueryBuilder.andExecuteReturningRef(RallyQueryBuilder.java:65)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.createRepository(RallyConnector.java:187)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.service.RallyService.updateChangeset(RallyService.java:46)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyPlugin.perform(RallyPlugin.java:109)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
    rally update plug-in error: could not update TaskDetails entry: null
com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyAssetNotFoundException
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.utils.RallyQueryBuilder.andExecuteReturningObject(RallyQueryBuilder.java:84)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.queryForTaskById(RallyConnector.java:107)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.service.RallyService.getTaskObjectByStoryRef(RallyService.java:140)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.service.RallyService.updateRallyTaskDetails(RallyService.java:108)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.RallyPlugin.perform(RallyPlugin.java:117)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:782)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:723)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1037)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1763)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Build step 'Update Rally Task and ChangeSet' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

My commit message  was :

```
US109 for task TA52 with status: in progress
```

I am not getting what wrong i am doing.Let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: Please open case with Rally for troubleshooting this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of that plugin.

This happens when the credentials you're using to access CA (née Rally) don't have permission to create a `Changeset` object on the Work Item you referenced (US109). The quick fixes are to make sure your Work Items belong to a Project to which your credential user has access to, or have an administrator grant your credential user access to more Projects.

I'm currently working on making the exception into a silent failure (i.e. the logs will show that the `Changeset` wasn't created but the build won't fail because of it).

If you have any more issues please feel free to file a report on [the plugin's website](https://github.com/jenkinsci/rally-plugin). Sorry for the poor error message!